# Why Does Implementing an ActionListener make the applet shrink(virtually)?

Tags: java, applet, awt, actionlistener, mousemotionlistener

I recently made a MakeDots class in java that when you drag the mouse, it makes dots(yay!). I implemented a MouseMotionListener for that. It worked fine. Then I added some buttons to change the colors of the dots. I added ActionListeners for that. Once I did that, the color-changing worked, but I could only draw in the very tiny borders of the buttons! Why does this happen? How do I fix it? If you need me to post my code just say in the comments, and I will do so.

CODE:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class MakeDots extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener{
    private Graphics graphics = null;
    private Color dotColor = Color.red;
    private Button setRed;
    private Button setPink;
    private Button setPurple;
    private Button clrBtn;
    public void init() {
        setRed = new Button("Red");
        setPink = new Button("Pink");
        setPurple = new Button("Purple");
        clrBtn = new Button("Clear");
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        this.add(setRed);
        this.add(setPink);
        this.add(setPurple);
        this.add(clrBtn);
        setRed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dotColor = Color.red;
            }
        });
        setPink.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dotColor = Color.pink;
            }
        });
        setPurple.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dotColor = new Color(80, 0, 80);
            }
        });
        clrBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clear();
            }

        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        graphics = g.create();
        clear();
    }
    public void drawDot(int x, int y) {
        graphics.setColor(dotColor);
        graphics.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }


    public void clear() {
        Dimension d = this.getSize();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();
            drawDot(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to post your code if you want help

Comment: You added the buttons to the drawing canvas, the buttons will consume mouse events. Try adding the buttons to there own container and layout the drawing surface and buttons to separate areas of the main container

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you give me an example? I don’t quite understand you…

Comment: You've added your buttons to the same surface you are trying to paint to, you need to separate the into different containers. Why are you using AWT based API? It's over 15 years out of date. You should also not be maintaining a reference to the Graphics context and paint out side of the paint cycle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things you might want to do.
 Lose the practice of writing `actionPerformed(...)` everytime you add an `actionListener()`. Just use `getActionCommand()` to check which button triggered the event. Also,create a global object of `Color()` and update it in `actionPerformed()`